# Folium (Mapas con diferentes fuentes de datos)

Tags: python, pandas, mapa, folium

Estoy empezando a utilizar Folium para generar mapas interactivos, de la cual necesito generar un mapa con marcadores  que provienen de diferentes fuentes de datos, es decir, tengo esto:

```
#Fuentes de Datos

data1 = pd.read_excel('./data/Relevancia.xls')
data2 = pd.read_excel('./data/Zona.xls')
```

La data1 (Relevancia) tiene la siguiente estructura (Son mas de 500 datos):

```
   lat         lon       tipo evento

--------------------------------------
-99.1483     19.2419      Malo
-99.2411     19.0561      Bueno
-99.5083     18.3361      Bueno
-99.2078     19.7153      Bueno
-99.9289     20.2961      Malo
```

La data2 (Zona) tiene la siguiente estructura (Son 100 datos):

```
   x          y         localidad

--------------------------------------
-99.1483     19.2419      CDMX
-99.2411     19.0561      Jalisco
-99.5083     18.3361      Edo Mexico
-99.2078     19.7153      Jalisco
-99.9289     20.2961      CDMX
```

Lo que requiero es generar un mapa donde contenga las dos fuentes de datos. He realizado esto pero sin resultados esperados:

```
#Creo el mapa
centro = [20.5223, -99.8883]
map = folium.Map(location=centro, zoom_start=8)
#Mostrar Mapa
map
```

Genero los marcadores para la data1:

```
Latitudes = data1['lat'].to_list()
Longitudes = data1['lon'].to_list()
Popups = data1['Tipo evento'].to_list()

marcador1 = []
for lat, long, pop in list(zip(Latitudes, Longitudes, Popups)):
    fLat = float(lat)
    fLon = float(long)
    if pop == "Malo":
        folium.Marker(
        location=[fLat,fLon],
        popup= pop,
        icon = folium.Icon(color = 'red', icon="remove-sign"))
    elif pop == "Bueno":
        folium.Marker(
        location=[fLat,fLon],
        popup= pop,
        icon = folium.Icon(color = 'green', icon="ok-sign"))

marcador1.append([lat, long, pop])
```

Genero los marcadores para la data2:

```
Latitudes1 = data2['x'].to_list()
Longitudes1 = data2['y'].to_list()
Popups1 = data2['descripcion'].to_list()

marcador2 = []

for lat1, long1, pop1 in zip(Latitudes1, Longitudes1, Popups1):
    fLat1 = float(lat1)
    fLon1 = float(long1)
    folium.Marker(
        location=[fLat1,fLon1],
        popup= pop1,
        icon = folium.Icon(color = 'red', icon='home'))

marcador2.append([lat1, long1, pop1])
```

Procedo añadir atributos y marcadores al mapa:

```
# Creamos dos grupos para los marcadores
Atributo1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Relevancias')
Atributo2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Zonas')

map.add_child(Atributo1)
map.add_child(Atributo2)

# Añado los marcadores al grupo que pertenecen, no al mapa
marcador1.add_to(Atributo1)
marcador2.add_to(Atributo2)
# Ahora si añado los grupos al mapa
Atributo1.add_to(map)
Atributo2.add_to(map)
# Ademas se añade el control de capas
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)
#Mostrar Mapa
map
```

El resultado es error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-48f67a4d9c56> in <module>
      7 
      8 # Añado los marcadores al grupo que pertenecen, no al mapa
----> 9 marcador1.add_to(Atributo1)
     10 marcador2.add_to(Atributo2)
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add_to'

Pase los marcadores a una lista pero quizás no estoy entendiendo el concepto bien, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionar. Era por temas de actualización o recarga del mapa, donde volviendo a correr el código, ya se puede visualizar los marcadores separados por capas.